# EF Core - Select on Include and ThenInclude

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2.1 and i have a Model `SettingInformation`. The `SettingInformation` has a Property `Setting As ICollection(Of Setting)`.
The `Setting` Property has several Properties like `Client As Client`, `User as User` and also `Workspace As Workspace`. It's a bit complicated. Please see the Attached Diagram-Image.

[Model-Diagram(Part of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkDHY.png)

Now i have the problem, that i'd like to get the complete Information of a `Settinginformation`.
The following code i have to get all Informations of a SettingInformation

```
Public Async Function GetCompleteSettingInformations(settingInfoId As Integer) As Task(Of SettingInformation)
    Dim q As IQueryable(Of SettingInformation) = GetSettingInfoDefaultQuery()

    q = q.Where(Function(s) s.SettingInformationId = settingInfoId)
    q = q.Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.User) _
        .Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.Workspace) _
        .Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.Client) _
        .Include(Function(i) i.Protocol)

    Dim ret = Await q.SingleOrDefaultAsync
    Return ret
End Function
```

OK, this code works, but now i'd like to refactor this, because for example, I do not need the `UserImage` or the 'FailedLogins' of User when the 'LinkedToUser' Property of 'Protocol' is not nothing.

What i needed:

- The complete 'SettingInformation' - OK easy
- The 'Settings' From 'SettingInformation' (ICollection) - OK i can get this with the Include but in 'Settings':

  - only the 'UserName', 'FirstName' and 'LastName' from 'User' if 'User' is not Nothing
  - only the 'ClientShortName' and 'ClientLongName' of 'LinkedToClient' if 'Client is not Nothing
  - only the 'WorkspaceName' and 'WorkspaceLocation' of 'Workspace' id the 'Workspace' is not Nothing.

I hope so here is anybody who can help me to optimize this Query because now i also cat for example the UserImage for each Setting and this results in a long loadingtime.

EDIT:

OK, now i have tried to do that with EagerLoading. But the Select is ignored. But why? the following code:

```
'Alle WorkspaceIDs ermitteln für welche es Settingmodifikationen gibt
        Dim wsIds As List(Of Integer) = ret.Settings.Where(Function(u) u.WorkspaceId.HasValue).Select(Function(u) u.WorkspaceId.Value).ToList
        Await ContextInternal.Workspaces.Where(Function(u) wsIds.Contains(u.WorkspaceId)) _
        .Select(Function(su) New Workspace() With {.WorkspaceName = su.WorkspaceName, .WorkspaceLocation = su.WorkspaceLocation, .WorkspaceDesciption = su.WorkspaceDesciption, .WorkspaceId = su.WorkspaceId, .Settings = su.Settings}).AsTracking.LoadAsync
```

Loads all workspaces that are related in Protocols. I will only get the columns ID, Description, Location and Name. But i get ALL Columns?
The following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT [u].[WorkspaceId],
       [u].[CreatedBy],
       [u].[CreatedOn],
       [u].[CreationTimestamp],
       [u].[DeletedFlag],
       [u].[DeletedTimestamp],
       [u].[LastUpdateBy],
       [u].[LastUpdateOn],
       [u].[LastUpdateTimestamp],
       [u].[WorkspaceDesciption],
       [u].[WorkspaceLastOnline],
       [u].[WorkspaceLocation],
       [u].[WorkspaceLocked],
       [u].[WorkspaceName]
FROM   [Workspaces] AS [u]
WHERE  [u].[WorkspaceId] IN (1)
ORDER  BY [u].[WorkspaceId]
```

Comment: Sorry. The above code is a bit wrong. I dont need all the Includes. I only need the following:
' q = q.Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.User).Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.Workspace).Include(Function(i) i.Settings).ThenInclude(Function(i) i.Client).Include(Function(i) i.Protocol)'

Comment: Please edit your question and put in the correct code

Comment: Conditional Includes are not supported. You better load the related data afterwards, conditionally.

Comment: @binaryfunt - Thanks - Done